# Get Attribute Value using Attribute Code in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have Attribute Code. Am trying to fetch value but this code is not fetching attributes values that are in the decimal table!

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can get attributeValue using following code

if it is a custom attribute

```
$products = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
if(is_object($products->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode))){
    return $products->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I used this.

```
$attribute_value = $_product->getData($attributeCode);
```

It's Working!

Answer (score 4):

U Can used this and Get  Custome And Defult attributes Option Data,
For Example

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$atrributesRepository  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository');
$selectOptions = $atrributesRepository->get('AttributeCode')->getOptions();
foreach ($selectOptions as $selectOption) {
    print_r($selectOption->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to get attributes value :

```
$eavConfig = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config'); 
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); 
$alloptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(); 
foreach($alloptions as $option) { 
    $label = $option['label']; 
    $AllOptionsArr[$label][] = $option['value']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->create()->load($productId);
$attributeValue = $product->getData('yourattribute_code');
```